# Extends in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me understand this code? Seems too convoluted to me.

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};


var PageView = (function (_super) {
    "use strict";

    __extends(MyPageView, _super);

 function MyPageView(rootElement, viewModelParameter, calendarWeeksViewModel) {
});


}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Typescript and Google Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635901/typescript-and-google-closure), but that question is kind enough to explain where they got the code from. Further discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529285/prototype-chaining-constructor-inheritance). You can read up on javascript prototypal inheritance to learn more.

Comment: They got the code from the extends keyword in Typescript generated by tsc command and then unobfuscated. I don't see it as duplicate when work still go on trying understand the generated code and eventually clean it up and make a good answer to the question. The other question is about something else.

Answer (score 15):

So basically

```
__extends(MyPageView, _super);
```

Think in terms ofinheritance in a Object Oriented language. Where a class is extending a Super class or a base class..

So basically here  `MyPageView` will extend the functionality and implementation of the super class .

So lets say the base View has `method A() and method B()` and the current View has method C(), then you current view has access to all the three methods  `A() , B() and C()` in it's view.

But lets say  `MyPageView` has `method B()` , defined in it , then the method inside the view will take `precedence over the Method B()  of Super View`

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

Every function has a magical prototype property.

```
 var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
```

Cheks if that function is available in that context , if not define a function , that takes 2 arguments , The object that is to be extended and the object from which it is extended..

```
function __() { this.constructor = d; }
```

Defining a new function called `__` in which that **constructor** property of the context is bound to `object d`

```
 __.prototype = b.prototype;
```

The prototype property of the `Object __` is pointed to the `b.prototype` chain..

```
 d.prototype = new __();
```

The accessing of methods of `Super View` happens here , where you are setting the prototype property of the Object here..

So when the new instance is created, if the method is not available , then because of the `prototype`  on the object , it will check the methods in the `Super view` because it is available on the function `__` which is tied to `object d`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But I fail to understand what this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused about this code.
So I try this in the chrome and see what console showed.
without "this.constructor = d;" the constructor is Vector2
with "this.constructor = d;" the constructor is Vector3

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() {
        // mark this and try again
        this.constructor = d;
    }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};

function Vector2(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

}

Vector2.prototype.length2 = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
}

__extends(Vector3, Vector2)
function Vector3(x, y, z) {
    Vector2.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
}

Vector3.prototype.length3 = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
}

var v2 = new Vector2(1, 1);
var v3 = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
console.log(v3.constructor.prototype);
```

And you can compare with this 
finally I know why the original code do that

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {

    d.prototype = b.prototype;
};
```

I think the original code is equivalent to...

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    // function __() {
    //     // mark this and try again
    //     console.log(this);
    //     this.constructor = d;
    // }
    // __.prototype = b.prototype;
    // d.prototype = new __();

    d.prototype.__proto__ = b.prototype;
};
```