# Import module and use it in view

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

In an ASP.NET 5 project with Visual Studio 2015, we use Typescript classes with Knockout to generate our Javascript files. We use AMD and ES5.
Assume we have this first class :

**ActionViewModel.ts**

```
export class ActionViewModel {
     public Id: KnockoutObservable<number>;
     ...
 }
```

And another class that implements **ActionViewModel** in another Typescript file.

**action.ts**

```
 import { ActionViewModel } from 'ActionViewModel';

 class ActionVM extends ActionViewModel {
     ...
 }

 class ActionViewModelManager {
     private actionViewModel: ActionVM;
     ...
 }
```

**ActionViewModelManager** is used to manage the ViewModel. We load the first ViewModel thanks to the *import* keyword.

**The problem**

The Javascript file generated use a *define()* method to load the ActionViewModel.ts file.

```
 define(["require", "exports", 'ActionViewModel'], function (require, exports, ActionViewModel) {
     var ActionVM = (function (_super) {
     }

     var ActionViewModelManager = (function () {
         function ActionViewModelManager(withValidationRules) {
            this.actionViewModel = new ActionVM();
            ko.applyBindings(this.actionViewModel);
         }
         ...
     } 
});
```

But if I want to use my ActionViewModelManager in a view (Index.cshtml)

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var actionViewModelManager = new ActionViewModelManager();
        });
</script>
```

I can't because it said that ActionViewModelManager is not available : it's under the callback method's scope of the *define* method. So my question is : how can we use a class declared in a file where we import another class ?

**Edit : all JS generated**

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
define(["require", "exports", 'ActionViewModel'], function (require, exports, ActionViewModel) {
    var ActionVM = (function (_super) {
        __extends(ActionVM, _super);
        function ActionVM() {
            var _this = this;
            _super.call(this);

           this.clientSelected = function (args, handler) {
            ...
           };
           this.offreSelected = function (args, handler) {
            ...
           };
           this.submitAction = function (formElement) {
            ...
           };
        }

        return ActionVM;
    })(ActionViewModel);

    var ActionViewModelManager = (function () {
        function ActionViewModelManager(withValidationRules) {
            this.actionViewModel = new ActionVM();
            ko.applyBindings(this.actionViewModel);
        }

        ActionViewModelManager.prototype.SetId = function (valeur) { this.actionViewModel.Id(valeur); };
        ActionViewModelManager.prototype.SetDescription = function (valeur) { this.actionViewModel.Description(valeur); };

        return ActionViewModelManager;
    })();
});
```

I reduced the content of the file to be more readable.

Comment: Is there more to the generated Javascript you can share and / or can you change the output?

Comment: Thanks for your response, see the edit

Comment: this _might_ help. You need to know what `this` refers to, some parent class or namespace. if you knew that you could use `namesp.AVM` etc. Or following the answer here could get you there not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595220/extends-in-javascript

Comment: The fact is that I want to use ActionViewModelManager variable outside the define() method, but the file is generated so I have to achieve this from the Typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var actionViewModelManager = new ActionViewModelManager();
        });
</script>
```

Since you are using amd (I am assuming requirejs) you can do:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            require(['/path/to/actionvmfile'],function(res){
                var actionViewModelManager = new res.ActionViewModelManager();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Note: of course you should *export* the class for this to work i.e. `export class ActionViewModelManager`

Comment: Thanks for your response it helped. But I meet an new error : `JavaScript execution error: Script error for: ActionViewModel`. It seems that RequireJS cannot load ActionViewModel.js here : `define(["require", "exports", "ActionViewModel"]`

Comment: Use `./ActiveViewModel`

Comment: I found a solution pretty simple, and it allowed me to load Javascript files that I need in my page : https://jsfiddle.net/x6Ljtf5m/ but I found the baseUrl path ugly